# How to ignore 'src' directory in python project when making sphinx autodoc

Tags: python, python-sphinx, setup.py, autodoc

(alternative description could be 'how to rename a sphinx-autodoc package name?')

using sphinx version 1.7 on Python 2.7.13

---

I would like to automatically create documentation using docstrings and `sphinx-apidoc`.

My project structure is as follows:

```
myPythonProject      <- my Python package name and git repository.
|-- docs
|   |-- _build
|   |   |-- html     <- where final HTML doc is created.
|   |   
|   |-- apidocs      <- contains the autodoc created '.rst' files.
|   |-- _static
|   |-- _templates
|   |
|   | conf.py        <- 4 Sphinx doc files, auto generated with sphinx-quickstart.
|   | index.rst      <-
|   | make.rst       <-
|   | Makefile       <-
|
|
|-- src
|   | __init__.py    <- important for 'setup.py'.
|   | myModule1.py
|   | myModule2.py
|   | myModule3.py
|
| setup.py
```

The `myModule` files contain docstrings.

After performing the `sphinx-quickstart` with quite standard options *(extensions autodoc and intersphinx. No separated source and build directories. Adding `make.bat` and `Makefile` files.)*
And some minor change to the `conf.py` where I uncommented and changed:

```
# If extensions (or modules to document with autodoc) are in another directory,
# add these directories to sys.path here. If the directory is relative to the
# documentation root, use os.path.abspath to make it absolute, like shown here.

import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../'))
```

When running:
`sphinx-apidoc -f -o docs/apidocs src`

The docstrings are found but it is convinced **src** is my package name. It clearly does not observe my `setup.py` file or something. It does look at **__init__.py** though, if I remove it I can create docs with only modules, no package at all. But also this is not desired, but closer at least.

The content of **src** is installed as 'MyPythonProject'. Therefore `Setup.py` is configured as follows to install this package and leaving out the 'src' reference when importing:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='MyPythonProject',

    packages={'MyPythonProject': 'src'},
    package_dir={'MyPythonProject': 'src'},
```

(Is this an unorthodox structure? Otherwise I would also be interested in a more common layout which autodoc does support.)

---

Currently

```
sphinx-apidoc -f -o docs/apidocs src
sphinx-build -a -b html docs/ docs/_build/html
```

returns the following document:
[you can ignore the red.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yD6I.png)

### Question

How can I create documentation showing `myPythonProject.myModule1.def1()` it's docstring, and not `src.myModule1.def1()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative would be to include src in your path and specify the module without the src prefix.

So change your path setup to the src folder by replacing your line above with this in docs/conf.py:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../src'))
```

and in your sphinx index.rst change the automodule:: accordingly.

That way, you won't have that src. prefix to your class names.

Worked for me, anyway :-)

Comment: I couldn't test this answer, but I think it is a less hacky solution. Thanks for sharing!
Might this be a solution that became available in a later version?

Answer (score 0):

Rename `src` to `myPythonProject`. [Pyramid](https://github.com/pylons/pyramid) is one example that follows this convention.

Another example is explained in this [issue for Pyramid](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/issues/3022) and examples in [hupper](https://github.com/Pylons/hupper) and [pyramid_retry](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid_retry). However, you'll still have `MyPythonProject/src/MyPythonProject`, which although more unwieldly might not be as unsightly.

Ultimately whatever you name the directory that is the immediate parent that contains your package shall become the first part of the method's Python dotted name.

Comment: He Steve, thanks for your quick reply!
This certainly is a solution, but isn't it quite common to use a `src` directory for a projects code? Just because of that I thought there must be a workaround for this issue... Renaming would lead to a `myPythonProject/myPythonProject` folder, which I dislike a bit. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks a bunch Steve! So in other words, it is not supported and people use kind of workarounds to get the proper package naming in Sphinx (and are not bothered by the fact it must be structured like this ;) ).